# How to choose between a Software Service and a Software Agent?

Tags: service, software-design, agent

We have a system with a service that has a frontend so that users can manually use the service.  Users read information from a UI for the service and initiate actions through the UI by the service.  Nothing unusual here.

However, we would like to continue to allow the manual use of this service by users but we would also like to automate the user, e.g. have a software agent we write  access the same info and initiate the same type of actions.

Of course, the software agent wouldn't need to use the UI, it could query the view API and send commands to the write API. We can do this as we have a nice separation between our front-end UI and backend service.

My question is should we be automating a user by creating an agent like this OR should we be reimplementing the user as another service that interacts with the original service (e.g. an event-driven service)?

Either way the agent or service will be encapsulated within our system. The question is whether this component should use the service as the user would (but not through the UI) or implement equivalent functionality as a service

Thanks in advance for any thoughts, suggestions or pointers.

Cheers,
Ashley.

PS I am using the term "software agent" here because the component is somewhat replicating how a user would work, i.e. responding to information and executing actions.  I don't mean this agent is an AI or mobile etc.

Answer (score 0):

If automating the user is a feature of your application it makes sense to model it as a service to encapsulate that behavior. If the automation is for development/testing only, you might want to just script it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer clonq.  The automated user is to be a feature of the application and its behaviour will be encapsulated.  The question is more about whether this component should command the service (as the user would) or implement the functionality as an independent service?